# Cordova 5.2.x Geolocation not Accurate

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, geolocation

I have the following code in my app:

```
var geo = { lat: 0, lon: 0 };
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function( position ) {
       // set global vars
       geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
       geo.lon = position.coords.longitude;
    },
    function( error ) {
       // handle error
       geolocationError( error );
    },
    { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }
);
```

For one reason or another the location that I get in my app using the above code is very different (100's of meters, sometimes a 1KM or more) than what is displayed in the native map application (i.e. iOS Maps). Why is this?

It's particularly a problem in places where there is no Wifi and I am indoors. For example, recently in an airport my position in the native map application was very accurate; I was positioned in the right terminal - but when I opened my app and refreshed it many times over several minutes the position wasn't anywhere near the terminal I was in, in fact I was about 1KM from the airport.

What do I need to do to get at the very least, the geolocation that the native apps are able to get?

Comment: do you have cordova-plugin-geolocation plugin installed?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue multiple times before - there isn't anything you can really do about it even if you set `enableHighAccuracy` to `true`. It's an issue with the HTML5 geolocation method. Turning on wifi and bluetooth increases the accuracy, but you can't guarantee a user will do that every time.

Best of luck.